# How can I use undetected_chromedriver to __init__ function?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I have this project where I have to write a lot of code so I try to break my code into `modules` and `packages` where you have a **init** python file and whatnot.
When I tried it with `normal selenium webdriver`, it worked successfully. But when I switched to selenium `undetected_chromedriver`, it still worked but it also gave this huge wall of error. **I also want it to open with incognito mode** using `class` but no matter what I tried, I still couldn't figure out how

Here is my code. I have a directory named "WEBTEST", which includes python file named "**init**" and "web_file". Here is the code inside the "web_file" for `normal selenium webdriver`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os

class WEB(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"C:\Desktop"):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super().__init__()

    def land_URL(self):
        self.get('https://google.com/')
```

And I have this "bot" python file **outside of that directory** to call those code above

```
from WEBTEST.web_file import WEB
import time

with WEB() as w:
    w.land_URL()
    time.sleep(2)
    w.quit()
```

It worked successfully. Then when I switched to `undetected_chromedriver` like this:

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time
import os

class WEB(uc.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r"C:\Desktop"):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super().__init__()

    def land_URL(self):
        self.get('https://google.com/')
```

It **worked** but it **also** gave this wall of error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\ProjectWeb\bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    with WEB() as w:
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 795, in __exit__
    self.service.stop()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 145, in stop
    self.send_remote_shutdown_command()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 124, in send_remote_shutdown_command
    request.urlopen(f"{self.service_url}/shutdown")
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 519, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 536, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1377, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 1352, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 1375, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\http\client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py", line 706, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Please help, how can I fix this, and also how can I add **incognito mode** for it? While still using `class`?

--------edit-----------

So I tried Seleniumbase, I created this Directory that included "init" and "test" python file, and this is the code in the "test" python file:

```
from seleniumbase import Driver

class web():
    def __init__(self, uc=True, incognito=True):
        self.driver = Driver(uc=True, incognito=True)

    def land_url(self):
        self.get('https://www.google.com/')
```

And here is the code of the "bot" python file which is outside of that Directory to call it as a module

```
from directory.test import web
x = web()
x.land_url()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase)'s UC Mode with incognito mode to do it.

First `pip install seleniumbase`, and then run the following script with `python`:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver
import time

driver = Driver(uc=True, incognito=True)
driver.get("https://nowsecure.nl/#relax")
time.sleep(8)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: thank you but how can i write it in "class" to make it a module?

Comment: As seen in https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/plugins/driver_manager.py, there's a ``Driver`` function that can be made into a module via the context manager ``DriverContext``. Passing ``uc=True`` enables UC mode.

Comment: is that UC mode a "undetected-chrome" mode? seleniumbase has that in it? can i ask whether if seleniumbase can bypass the recapcha better than just "undetected-chrome"?

Comment: UC mode is the undetected-chromedriver mode included with seleniumbase. It can help with bypassing detection.

Comment: Sorry for answer this late but I keep getting errors no matter what I try.  I got "is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" error so I added the full path of both "chromedriver.exe" and "uc.exe" to the environment variable but it still couldn't work

Comment: I thought my laptop was broken so I borrowed my friend's one to try it out. The normal code lines of seleniumbase worked out fine, but when I turned it into a module, using "class", I got a different error of "AttributeError: object has no attribute 'get' "

Comment: If you're looking for a different way to structure the code, there are different SeleniumBase Syntax Formats to choose from: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/syntax_formats.md

Comment: I tried to replace "get" with "open" to open an url like in your article, but it's still the same "AttributeError" thing. I just edited my question and added the code I did for Seleniumbase above, could you check it yourself to see if Seleniumbase can work as a module with "class","init" and whatnot?

Comment: Example with a class: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/uc_cdp_events.py

Comment: I tried the exact code, it still gave me the "AttributeError" :( furthermore, I don't understand why but it opened 2 chrome windows, one was the normal mode and the other was the incognito mode, and none of them could open any website. Could you try the seleniumbase code I added in my question to see if it's the problem?

Comment: The code in your current Edit section is incorrect. See the available Syntax Formats for structuring SeleniumBase tests with classes: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/help_docs/syntax_formats.md (You can also enable options by passing them on the command-line, eg ``--uc``, ``--incognito``. Many formats require running with ``pytest``.)

Comment: Can you tell me where is incorrect in my edit code? Because 1 - none of those format is importing Driver like your answer code about seleniumbase above, but importing BaseCase. 2 - none of those format has "init" function, is it possible to make a module without an "init" function or python file?

Comment: In your example, you want `self.driver.get`, instead of `self.get`. As for `BaseCase`, it already includes the `Driver` options, but now you would pass them on the command-line with `pytest` (eg `pytest --uc --incognito`). The `__init__` isn't required when creating a class, but it can be useful.

Comment: I did try `self.driver.get` instead of `self.get`, still the same `AttributeError`. As for `BaseCase`, I tried the exact code from your articles, the results either gave me 2 windows at the same time when I only need 1, or gave me the `is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file.` when I already added the full path of .exe file to the environment variable

Comment: Furthermore, in BaseCase, it's good that it don't need `__init__`, but it also combines all code into 1 `define function` when I need MULTI `define functions` in 1 class, a def function to open the website, a def function to click,... since I have to code A LOT. So I don't think BaseCase work for me if it can't connect multi `define functions` in 1 class. So can BaseCase connect multi `define functions` in 1 class? If it can, can you show me an example because I didn't see it in the articles you sent me

Comment: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/test_swag_labs.py

Comment: And sir, I really really appreciate your help, but to a newbie, can you help me realize what I did wrong in my current knowledge instead of introducing me different new knowledge? I asked about what's wrong with my `uc`, you told me to use `seleniumbase driver`, I used it but it gave me error so I asked why, then you told me to use `basecase` and `pytest`, I used them but it still gave me error so I asked why again, then you gave me `basecase` examples. What's about those errors? Can you tell me why those errors appear? And can you try with `base driver` first instead of going to new things?

Comment: I forgot to add, just like my first question, i want to create a `module` that I can call its function from a different python file, that's why I use `class` and `__init__`, not a `solitary python file`, because so far, your examples are `solitary python file` that I can run without using `class`